# Reasons for the blue screen of death in Windows 7 logs

Tags: windows-7, windows, logging, bsod

Lately I see a blue screen of death a lot and want to know why it appears. Where should I gather the information so the problem can be diagnosed best?
Couldn't find anything in C:\Windows\Logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really tend to be fond of [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) for analyzing BSODs, or you can use [nirsoft's blue screen view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) - the former is easier to use, the latter lets you look at bluescreens. I believe both of these analyze the windows minidump file (often at %windir%/minidump) [and MS has a knowledge base on reading it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263)