# Error 10016 Causes computer crash

Tags: windows-10, crash

I was just watching youtube and all of a sudden my laptop crashed. No blue screen, just shut off when it was plugged in and had full power. (I checked right away that it was plugged in, and that the surge protector was on.)

My first impulse was to check the the event logs. I found the following:

```
The previous system shutdown at 6:12:03 PM on ‎3/‎2/‎2017 was unexpected.

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>4</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-03T00:33:58.276107600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>28137</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DLuxCru</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">7</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
  + System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  EventLog 

  - EventID 6008 

   [ Qualifiers]  32768 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2017-03-03T00:34:28.014842800Z 

   EventRecordID 28123 

   Channel System 

   Computer DLuxCru 

   Security 


- EventData 

   6:12:03 PM 
   ‎3/‎2/‎2017 


   161929 


   E10703000400020012000C0003006601E10703000500030000000C0003006601600900003C000000010000006009000001000000B00400000100000000000000 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words

0000: 000307E1 00020004 000C0012 01660003 
0010: 000307E1 00030005 000C0000 01660003 
0020: 00000960 0000003C 00000001 00000960 
0030: 00000001 000004B0 00000001 00000000 


In Bytes

0000: E1 07 03 00 04 00 02 00   á.......
0008: 12 00 0C 00 03 00 66 01   ......f.
0010: E1 07 03 00 05 00 03 00   á.......
0018: 00 00 0C 00 03 00 66 01   ......f.
0020: 60 09 00 00 3C 00 00 00   `...<...
0028: 01 00 00 00 60 09 00 00   ....`...
0030: 01 00 00 00 B0 04 00 00   ....°...
0038: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
```

Beyond that I found nothing that is logged as an error on a relevant timescale. There appears to be a gap of several hours in the log - 2:07 to 6:33 even though the computer was active and watching YouTube. Could just be that it wasn't doing much, but I guess I'd figure I'd see more in the system log preceding an unexcepted shutdown.

Does anyone have an idea on what might have caused this? Googling doesn't offer many good tips, and the absence of useful data in the log doesn't tell me much. If it doesn't happen again I won't be to worried about it, (and I won't put a ton of effort into debugging the issue unless it's a repeat offender) but I would like to spot potential causes in case this is more serious than I think.

Comment: whocrashed tends to be what I use here. Does a decent job at quick, detailed analysis of crashes.

Comment: What's whocrashed?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/359449/10165 tends to be my usual approach to finding these issues